# Covariation integrals

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am new to stochastic integral. Let $X^{(i)}$ be two square integrable martingales, such that :

$E(X_t^{(1)^2}) \leq  E(X_t^{(2^2)}) < \infty, t \geq 0$

We set $\hat{X_t}^{(i)} = \int_0^t X_u^{(i)} du$ $i = 1,2$

I have to compute $[\hat{X_t^{(i)}}, \hat{X_t^{(i)}}]$

I find

$[\hat{X_t^{(i)}}, \hat{X_t^{(i)}}] = \int_0^t \int_0^t X_u^{(i)}X_v^{(i)} du dv$

But I do not know if It is correct and if I can simplify.

I wonder if the covariation is $0$ in fact. Do you confirm ?

Thanks in advance.